# Does a Turkish National living/working in Norway require Visa to enter UK on holiday?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, turkish-citizens

Does a Turkish National (Turkish passport) living/working in Norway, who has a 3 year Resident Permit require a Visitor's Visa to enter UK for holiday?  Or is he exempted under the EAA rules?

If Visa required, how long does it take to acquire?

Comment: In the question text, what does "[netherlands]" mean?

Comment: Am a newbie, did not wish to delete that in case it would not post it to relevant section.  Should I delete it now from my origianl enquiry? or will it mess things up and I not be able to see the first and your answers to my question?

Comment: You can delete it; use the "edit" button below your question's text. The text you do not delete, as well as the Answers and Comments, will remain.

Comment: Thank you so much David.  Am truly sorry for the late response.

However, I have no clue of what I am doing in this forum, so when you say use the edit button???  could you please send me a link to where I should be editing this please? pretty please  ANTICIPATORY THANKS.

Comment: Thanks for checking back in. User CatchAsCatchCan has edited your question to remove the unnecessary text. If you want to edit, do this: below the text of your question, you'll see the words "Share," "Edit, Follow" and perhaps "Close" and "Flag." Click on "Edit." Then you'll see a box with your original text, where the text can be changed or deleted. When you're done editing, click the "Save Edits" button at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to check this is to use the UK government’s [check if you need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/) page.

[In your case](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/turkey/tourism/no) it tells us that you need a visa.

Notes:

- In general, visa requirement are based on citizenship, not residence. There are exceptions, mostly for transit, but not in your case.
- The UK is not part of the EEA.

According to https://www.gov.uk/guidance/visa-decision-waiting-times-applications-outside-the-uk the regular waiting time is about 3 weeks, but currently stands at around 6 weeks. There may be expedited services (priority in 5 days, super priority the next day). In Norway there seems to be priority service (limited availability, 300 EUR additional cost) but no super-priority.

Comment: TY jcaron.  Am totally confused, UK Home Office, Norwegian Embassy in UK, &iVisa company all give different responses.  

ACCORDING TO https://www.gov.uk/eu-eea
QUOTE
You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit (unless you’re exempt

EXEMPTIONS
You do not need a visa if you have one of the following:
    a visa for Canada, New Zealand, Australia or the USA (this can be used for travel to any country)
    a permanent resident visa issued by Australia or New Zealand
    a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country or Switzerland
UNQUOTE

Comment: @Milagrin The exemptions are all for transit, not for visiting/holiday.

Comment: @Milagrin You can also check using the IATA website https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Comment: I am terribly sorry for not responding before.  I truly appreciate the trouble you took to answer my question.

Thank you kindly jcaron  I have now left it in the hands of the traveller. UK embassy does not respond with requested answers. I give up!  Thank you. Milagrin